# JetBrains Rider remote debugger error : Unable to start debugging. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, remote-debugging, rider, jetbrains-rider

I just ran into problem described in header. Trying to connect to w3wp process on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Rider cannot find the path described in error to upload it's files on server. You need just create this folder